# Joining multiple parameters in a Solr filter query

Tags: solr, filter

When doing a filter query in SOLR, what is the difference between these

```
1. fq=+gallery_type:0^100 +content_length:14
```

and

```
2. fq=(gallery_type:0^100 AND content_length:14)
```

The filter for content_length (which I'm using for debugging purposes, I have a different filter I want to add) only gets applied on the second version, but from what i see here http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq the first version should be used for multiple conditions.

I basically want to add an extra filter to existing filters that are currently joined with "+"

Thanks

Comment: By the way Filter queries does not apply scoring. So it wouldn't effect the boosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fq=+gallery_type:0^100 +content_length:14 => depends of (schema.xml)

```
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
```

fq=(gallery_type:0^100 AND content_length:14) => define operator

Comment: Ah I get it now. The default operator is OR, that's why it wasn't working as I expected. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The "+" sign says that the query term is **MANDATORY** So for your first query BOTH must be present.

If the default operator is set to OR or AND it wont make a difference as both must be present.

Therefore both queries will give the same result